# Default location where docker images are saved on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, diskspace, image-size

I installed docker on Windows 10 Pro and created/pulled several images some as big as 953 MB.

I'm however interested to know in what directory are all the images stored.

I checked Hyper-V manager for `Virtual Hard Disks` and `Virtual Machines` directories but they are not more than 500 KBs

Below is the snapshot of the same.

[image]

My docker was installed with default settings.

After reading some forums I also checked the following directories like `C:\ProgramData\Docker` and `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V` but they are 0 bytes in size.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro

I did inspect an image but it does not contain any data indicating the image file on Windows. See below:

```
C:\Users\HOME>docker image inspect myfirstcont

"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
        "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/rtdgjoc6gg00v0l0h381fy4gw/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/squ8lhqlwajh2yv1ecc9yltaj/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/819dca1c2bb7ce54c13c0c7421e5804538a9605b4daf0f8ab52a47024cb96d29/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/12c27601a0dc2397cf87405d2ece5757d5f6d45e1c38e1c58cef4de1964ea04f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d0862b28727db9ac5a3fed6eb3caad3968b8824919c4b5de742a25ca89b7b1dd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c82c5574cb3aac2600976a38093c98e575c6d3e32aee7b9e548dc4f8ed3678b9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5461792a7a73055859f45c624450a4d06f212e4437d9d1f81a012a2fa932a620/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f130395cf64a6182fdb6bd8f18e4a64f5763856464cded60f01214b8d695e56c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a122314ee57fd42eb80b9d367cc579402afd36d0484579b97b0074d692cb0ec2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e2c0039edd02283fce0f7e7a3f3bd798d2597b7c26ad85280db804d83697d238/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0bf984e8907a11ac4f000f1d7909f61dd6aac497517c6fb2a6947cf683ad3993/diff",
        "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/lv5akhtcyzkioljls2bfolgdu/merged",
        "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/lv5akhtcyzkioljls2bfolgdu/diff",
        "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/lv5akhtcyzkioljls2bfolgdu/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
},
```

Can you please suggest where can I find the image files for all the docker images I pulled?

Comment: Is your docker using WSL or Hyper-V ?

Comment: @Bala using WSL

Comment: I find the below files `C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx` (9GB) and `C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx` (1 GB) however i wish to see individual images and i wish to manually move a few selected images not all in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using WSL2 with Docker Desktop, a new distro is created called `docker-desktop-data`, which is also where all your image layers are stored. You can find all your layers under `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2`.

You will have to `docker image inspect <image_id>` and look for `GraphDriver.Data` to find which directories are related to your docker images.

Comment: I was looking for a specific docker image on my Windows but the `GraphDriver.Data` for the image does not have any Windows path but only Unix path mentioned. Thus getting a single image as a Windows file is not achieved by your answer. Updated the Original post with `GraphDriver.Data`

Comment: @Ashar Getting an image as a "Windows file" is not possible, that's not how Docker stores images. They are merely a set of instructions scattered across multiple image layers out of which a container is built.

Comment: The directories under `GraphDriver.Data` are the image layers that are stored under `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2`, they're only displayed as Unix paths. When you look at the SHA256 of `GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir`, you will find the image layer under the mentioned Docker distro.